# Are there any CoffeeScript formatters Vim plugin?

Tags: vim, coffeescript, formatter

I've recently started writing CoffeeScript in Vim.

When writing JS code, there's a plugin call [Jsbeautify](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2727) which helps format the JS code.

I notice that there are some IDEs that have some kind of formatting feature for CoffeeScript, but I wonder if there is a similar Vim plugin which can format CoffeeScript as well.

Does anybody have some recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

google, search result 1.

https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script/

says it handles indentation.

Comment: However, when running gg=G using this plugin, the code breaks. There is a longstanding bug present in the indent file.